# how to create oauth2 token for github enterprise under organization?

Tags: oauth, github, oauth-2.0, github-api

I'm trying to create an oauth2 token for an organization. This seems to be impossible (or at least I'm not finding it). This will be used for various one of scripts (non-web use). This is also for an enterprise github (github.company.com/api/v3 vs api.github.com).

I created one under my user like this:

```
curl -u 'username:password' -d '{"scopes":["scripts!"],"note":"test?"}' https://github.company.com/api/v3/authorizations
```

and that worked as expected. What I can't figure out is the magical way to do this under an organization since an organization doesn't have basic auth credientals. I haven't been able to find any documentation that tells me how to give something a client id/secret and get an oauth token out of it, which *seems* like the thing I would want to do.

If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment of this writting [this is not supported](https://twitter.com/fernandezpablo/status/312389762017263617)

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a token for the org directly, but if you have a dev account that has full access to the org, you can do this (sort of), just in a round about way.

1. Create the oauth token for that dev account.
2. When registering the token with a 3rd party (e.g. Confluence, Jira, etc...) you can specify the org as the "Team"/"Owner".

This will use the dev accounts credentials but only grant access to things under the org (not full access to the dev account's repos, etc...).

I came across your question when trying to link a github org account with my company's Jira account, so figured I'd share.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, 1 year later you've helped me out greatly! About to open source the site for my Algorithm Implementations repo. Thank  you

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's not possible currently. As you say -- the organization itself doesn't have any credentials associated with it. So, the only way to do it is to do it yourself, as a developer, with your credentials.

This might be a cool feature request to send to the GitHub folks.

Answer (score 0):

Update: this setting is now under

**Developer settings > OAuth Applications**